# Imputation of missing numeric values while preserving the absence of it

Tags: machine-learning, imputation

Before I dive into the Question itself I'll give a brief explanation of the data set and the problem

**The Data set**

I have a data set of roughly 20000 records and I intend to use it to train a classifier which classifies the a given record as '***Positive***' or '***Negative***'. The data set is also pretty imbalanced with a 5:1 ratio favoring the 'Positive' side.

One of the Features called '***Price***' within the Data set which contains a monetary value (thus is <0) and has a few missing values (about 200). When I analyzed the data set all the rows which had NaN for '***Price***' were classified as '***Negative***'.

**The Problem**

What would be the best strategy to impute this column? I came up with the following options

1. I could drop these rows but since all of them are from the '***Negative***'
   class, that doesn't seem viable
2. Impute it with a value an extreme value such as -1000.00 as it is a monetary value. While it may work in this situation. It would not work had the value also taken negative values. and I wish to learn a more generic approach to the problem.
3. Impute it as normal with a stategy such as 'mean' or 'nearest
       neighbour' which still could affect the performance as a majority of
       the classes are 'Positive'
4. I could add a new Column called 'wasCompleted' which has a value of 1 if there was a value for the 'Price' feature or 0 if there wasn't. And still go with an option like (2) or (3). Which would still not solve any issue within those stategies

Considering this scenario what would be the best option to consider to impute these values?

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one more option to consider:

5. Leave it as it is, and use ML method which can handle missing values much better than using any kind of imputation or creation of additional features. Such a method is e.g. LightGMB.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz Sionkowski for the recommendation. I will look into it. I was hoping to use Keras for the implementation but I still haven;t started so it doesn't really matter. Any insight on how to do it with keras or with any framework in general will be appreciated